# Multine line input - extract numbers using regex

Tags: regex, string, multiline

I have a multiline input string and I want to extract phone number only.
Right now the regex i have written is getting the numbers but also getting numbers between text in 2 and 3rd line. for example;

This is the multiline string;

```
123-(455)
Office365@gmail.com
```

and i am applying following regex

```
[(0-9),-]+
```

Now this regex is extracting `123-(456)` and `365`.
I don't want my regex to get numbers from `office365@gmail.com`

I have looked several regex but don't seem to get the one working for my case. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is one more example;

Phone
(209) 123-2345, (345) 123-7890
1 more
Email
xxx87@aol.com, abc87@lycos.com
Employment
some random text here
some random text here with number 123.

so i just want to extract below phone numbers from the regex
(209) 123-2345, (345) 123-7890

Comment: Which programming language do you use? Additionally, more examples to form a pattern would be useful.

Comment: is the number always alone in line? If so, you could just do `^[(0-9),-]+$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for word boundaries? You don't want to match any numbers within a word like `Office365`. You want to match numbers that have word boundaries before and after them.

This is what you need:

```
\b[(0-9),-]+(\b|\n)
```

I have to add the `\n` because without it doesn't match the closing bracket because apparently new lines are not word boundaries.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/HwV0XF/1).

Comment: Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/HwV0XF/2 Additionally, `(\b|n)` is redundant and can be written as `\b` alone. As of now the question remains unclear.

Comment: I have given one more example. The regex given by Fallenhero is works for me after removing $ from the regx.

Answer (score 0):

Given the two examples you've listed, this works:

```
^[(0-9),-]+$
```

simply by indicating that the allowed characters are the only characters allowed between the start and end of the line

Comment: Worth noting that this requires the multiline flag to be turned on.